# can I leave a job after two weeks?

Tags: new-job

Is it okay to quit a job if you're not interested any more? I want to quit the company, but my sister is also working here and I don't want to risk her employment.

Comment: In many countries you might still be in a probation period... which is exactly for cases like this. If you are already unhappy in this period, leave. Of course, give notice and do it in a professional way.

Comment: I don't know what country you're in, but I would be **very surprised** if they could legally terminate *your sister* just because you quit after two weeks.  That's a wrongful termination law suit waiting to happen.

Comment: Do you have a probation period? If so those are typically two way streets and either party can cut ties with no bad blood. Your sister should be no concern in this. Unless you both came on as a team, there would be no reason for the company to even consider her in your decision to leave.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, check the rules or contract you have agreed and whatever your reason, talk to your boss/manager. don't just disappear.